# How do I delete this cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

So I have had to use a cookie to remember a selection - awesome that works, but I also need to remove in under a on click event, also awesome... but that is just not working for me, here is what I am using to implement the onclick event (which seems to work as I tried an alert which was being triggered.)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dnn_ctr555_ProductSearch_rpData_cmdAdvSearch_0').click(function () {
        $.cookie('myDDIdx', null,{ path: '/' });
    });
});
```

Here is the script I am using to create the cookie

```
var sidx = document.cookie.indexOf("myDDIdx");
if(sidx != -1)
window.onload = function () { document.getElementById("Selection").selectedIndex =  document.cookie.substr(sidx + 8,1); }


<select id="Selection" class="sorter" onchange="document.cookie= 'myDDIdx = ' + this.selectedIndex + '; path=/;';location=this.options[[this.selectedIndex]].value" style="float:right;margin-right:8px;">
```

This is sending me up the wall path, I have nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using this jQuery library: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

From the readme documentation:

> ... *when deleting a cookie, you must pass the exact same path, domain and secure options that were used to set the cookie* ...

Since you're setting the cookie using `path=/`:

```
document.cookie= 'myDDIdx = ' + this.selectedIndex + '; path=/;'
```

To remove the cookie, you need to use:

```
$.removeCookie("myDDIdx", { path: '/' });
```

Answer (score -1):

just use this:

```
$.removeCookie("myDDIdx");
```

Comment: Also tried this and the cookie seems to be rather persistent... Its not going anywhere